# Tcp Server localhost client randomly disconnects

Tags: tcp, windows-server-2012

localhost Tcp connections randomly disconnecting. Running tcp client/server apps with simple echoing the server sees the local client connection breaking but any client connection over the network stays up. All local host connections get severed. One can immediately reconnect with no problem. This happens randomly and relatively rarely but is still problematic in my environment. Has anyone observed this pattern?

Comment: TCP is a huge protocol. Many things can be happening. Please specify how do you see that the connection is breaking? Is it server logs, RST packets in tcpdump? The more precise - the better.

Comment: I see this error: "The semaphore timeout period has expired" while I am sitting on a read for the tcp connection. Could you recommend anything (hopefully lightweight) to help gather more precise info next time this happens?

Comment: Can you replicate this problem with without using either SendFile or AcceptEx? Are you setting any read or write timeouts on the sockets?

Comment: I am not setting any read or write timeouts on the socket. I haven't tried SendFile or AcceptEx. The interesting thing is only the sockets running on localhost disconnect while those connecting over the network from another server stay connected at the same time.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of "Localhost" use 127.0.0.1

Localhost is used in Linux. Windows works better with 127.0.0.1.
Beats me, Google for explanation or just use the knowledge.